# How to tell if an image is loaded or cached in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Seems the .load() function doesn't fire if the image has been cached before. So if you want to make sure one images has loaded before you load and show another (i.e. Magnifier) you can't do something like:

```
$(img_to_load_first)
    .load(
        $(img_to_load_last)
            .src("2nd.png");
    )
    .src("1st.png");
```

So how does one ensure loading order in JQuery?

Comment: When is this code being run? Is it inside of a $(document).ready?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you'll have to do is handle your load bindings selectively.  You can verify load by testing the Image object property `complete`.

For example:

```
$('.load_selector').each(function(){

    if (!this.complete) {
        $(this).load(function(){
            // handle image load event binding here
        });
    } else {
        // handle image already loaded case
    }

});
```

Note that above, `this` (used alone) refers to the DOM reference to the image object provided by jQuery.

Comment: Was this helpful?  Note that you can fire your load handler in the `else` clause as above if that is required.

Comment: Any idea about compatibility on this?

Comment: Wide support, see browser matrix here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_complete.asp -- one thing to keep in mind is that you may want to test for a valid src attribute before checking the complete property.  Many browsers will return true for an empty src (eg: empty source is complete in that it is not loading / won't load)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Sparkey,

I'll give that a try but it looks good. I found a extensive discussion on the topic here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1007-jQuery-Attr-Function-Doesn-t-Work-With-IMAGE-complete.htm

which lead me to the "jQuery 'onImagesLoad' Plugin" here: http://includes.cirkuit.net/includes/js/jquery/plugins/onImagesLoad/1.1/documentation/

which seems to solve the issue like so:

```
$imgs.each(function(i, val){
    $(this).bind('load', function(){
        // ...
    }).each(function(){
        if (this.complete || this.complete === undefined){ this.src = this.src; } //needed for potential cached images
    });
});
```

Which pretty much boils down to what you said, only his completed check also test for "undefined".

Answer (score 2):

If you want to wrap all this functionality in a jQuery extension method, try this (which should work waiting for any number of images):

```
$.fn.imagesLoaded = function () {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    var count = this.length;
    this.each(function () {
        if (this.complete) {
            if (!--count) {
                def.resolve();
            }
        } else {
            $(this).load(function () {
                if (!--count) {
                    def.resolve();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return def.promise();
}
```

and then simply use like this:

```
$(img_to_load_first).imagesLoaded().done(function () {
    $(img_to_load_last).src("2nd.png");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if your image has a width or height to detect if it has already loaded.

For example:

```
var img = _content.find('img');
  if(img[0].width >0 || img[0].height > 0 ) {
  console.log('already loaded image');
  } else {
  img.on('load', function() {
    console.log('image loaded');
  });
}
```