# Detect image load by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

```
<img src="http://site.com/image.png" />
```

I change src of this image on `.click` event.

There can be loaded more than 20 different images, after changing `src`.

1) How do I know, was image already loaded (should be cached) or it has to be loaded?

2) How to run two different functions, for loaded and not?

Thanks.

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948672/how-to-tell-if-an-image-is-loaded-or-cached-in-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browser-independent way to detect when image has been loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821516/browser-independent-way-to-detect-when-image-has-been-loaded)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to attach an event handler for the `load event`:

**Update 2017**:

```
$('img').on('load', function() {
    alert('new image loaded: ' + this.src);
});
```

Plain JS/DOM:

```
imgNode.onload = () => {
    alert('new image loaded: ' + this.src);
};
```

Comment: how to run two different functions, for loaded and not?

Comment: @Happy: this event is fired regardless if the image is loaded from a server or the browser cache. I'm not aware of a possiblity to distinct between the two.

Comment: Note that as of jQuery 1.7, .on() is preferred to .bind()
The rest of the code is the same :)

Comment: This answer could really use an update. `bind()` has been superseded and deprecated for sometime now.