# Javascript display dynamic changing image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to refresh an image every 1 second. This picture is dynamically generated by my webcam, but this script sometimes display broken images when browser didnt yet load a picture before display. How to detect when picture is loaded and then change the diplay picture? 
I have a code like this:

```
    <img id="image" src="webcam.jpg">


<script>
setInterval(function() {
    var myImageElement = document.getElementById('image');
    myImageElement.src = 'webcam.jpg?rand=' + Math.random();
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: `500` is half a second, by the way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect image load by jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292819/detect-image-load-by-jquery)

Comment: @Liam he is not using jquery, why is then a possible duplicate of a jquery question?

Comment: The Op has tagged it jQuery. This typically means a jQuery solution is viable

Comment: Also a possible duplicate of [Browser-independent way to detect when image has been loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821516/browser-independent-way-to-detect-when-image-has-been-loaded)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should wait for the image to be loaded first, before replacing it.

For this, you can use different approaches. What I usually do, is to create another image which is not visible and replace the one visible once the previous image is loaded.

Your code should look like this if you want to follow this approach:

```
<img id="image" src="webcam.jpg">


<script>
setInterval(function() {
    var url = 'webcam.jpg?rand=' + Math.random();
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var myImageElement = document.getElementById('image');
        myImageElement.src = url;
    });
}, 1000);
</script>
```

What you can also do is play with css styles to make the image hidden or visible depending on the state, but that would make your image appear and disappear which is a bit ugly...

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use something like this:

```js
var _img = document.getElementById('pic'),
urlToImage = 'pic.jpg',
modified = false, lastModified = 0;

setInterval(function(){


fetch(urlToImage)
    .then(function(resp){
     var f = new File([resp],"file");
      
     switch(true) {
        case modified === false:
          lastModified = f.lastModified;
          modified = true; break;
          
          default:
          modified = false;
          if(lastModified < f.lastModified) {
            modified = true;
          }
    
      }
      
     return resp.blob();
    })
    .then(function(blobdata){
      switch(true) {
        case modified === true:
        var obj_url = URL.createObjectURL(blobdata);
       _img.src = obj_url;
      break;
      }
     
    });

},1000);
```

```html
<img src="" id="pic" alt="LOCAL pic here"/>
```

I think that looking at lastModified time in File properties is a good way to assume image was finished written on the server.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Try using this after loading the document

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
    var myImageElement = document.getElementById('image');
    myImageElement.src = 'webcam.jpg?rand=' + Math.random();
}, 500);
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: He is not using jquery, why adding a new dependency?

Comment: Well, one of the tags says jquery. If he's not using it, the tag should be removed.

Comment: jQuery is fine for this question, this answer though won't work. At all.

Comment: I used jquery, since he tagged this under jquery.

Comment: @Prags I can use jQuery, thats not a problem.

Comment: @Prags This solution not helps, problem is when script trying to display picture which is not yet saved 0 bytes or not yet loaded by browser and display broken image icon.