# javascript/jquery - recognize loaded from cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

I have image gallery and am updating front-end, is there a way to use javascript or jquery or any other front end technology to identify which image was loaded from cache? I would like to apply additional class for those items.

Thanks for any sugestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if an image is loaded or cached in JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948672/how-to-tell-if-an-image-is-loaded-or-cached-in-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer :

No

Long answer :

No, and there is a reason for that :
If you could know which element of tha page was from the cache, you could deduce that your user have been to the same page **or another page with the same element/ressource**. It would be a massive potential privacy breach.

A similar problem was arised with the changing color of link if they are visited (see http://dbaron.org/mozilla/visited-privacy for more info)

Comment: Well Özgur's answer shows that this privacy breach does nonetheless exist.

Comment: No, the image.complete only said if the image have finished loading, it does not tell if the image was loaded from cache or from a remote server

Comment: As javascript is not multithreaded, there is a good chance that if image.complete is true immediatly after setting the src attribute, the image was loaded from the cache.

Comment: That said, I haven't checked that the code actually works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function below. However it will load the image if not cached.

```
function isCached(src) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = src;
    return image.complete;
}
```

Comment: This will only tell of the image is loaded, not if it is loaded from cache

Comment: @RemyGrandin You are right. But if  image.complete is true after setting src it's most likely was loaded from the cache.